# How we create 3 parent and diffrent child using fork

Tags: c

How we Create multiple parent using fork() and for every parent we call fork() for child how we manage the child how we manage their addressess

```
For parent proceess i make this function

printf("\n Enter no of Parent processes:");
    scanf("%d",&p);
          for(i=0;i<p;i++)
        { 
           pid=fork();
if(pid==0)
    {
    exit(0);        
        }
else
        {
//parent process is %d",getpid())
        }
}
```

for create multiple child of diffrent above parent how manage

Comment: for ease of readability, please consistently indent the code.

Comment: when asking a runtime question, post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. documents why each header file is being included
3. performs the desired functionality
4. does not exit until all child processes are exited
5. properly checks for errors

and now the proposed code.

```
#include <stdio.h>      // scanf(), printf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>     // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <unistd.h>     // fork(), pid_t
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>   // waitpid()
#include <string.h>     // memset()


int main( void )
{
    unsigned int numProcesses;

    printf("\n Enter no of Parent processes:");
    if( 1 != scanf("%u",&numProcesses) )
    {
        perror( "scanf for number of processess failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    pid_t childPid[ numProcesses ];
    memset( childPid, '\0', numProcesses*sizeof(pid_t) );

    unsigned i;
    for( i=0; i< numProcesses; i++ )
    {
        childPid[i] = fork();
        switch( childPid[i] )
        {
            case 0:  // child
                {
                    pid_t childchildPid = fork();
                    switch ( childchildPid )
                    {
                        case 0: // child child
                            exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
                            break;

                        case -1: // fork error
                            perror( "fork by child failed" );
                            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                            break;

                        default:  // parent of child child
                            {
                                int status;
                                waitpid( childchildPid, &status, 0 );
                                exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case -1: // fork error
                perror( "fork by parent failed" );
                break;

            default:

                break;
        } // end parent switch
    } // end while loop

    int status;

    for( unsigned j = 0; j < i; j++ )
    {
        if( childPid[j] )
        {
            waitpid( childPid[j], &status, 0 );
        }
    }

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: sir why we need to create switch statement

Comment: a series of `if..else if... else` would do the job, Amongst reasons for the `switch()` statements are:  the `fork()` has three different return conditions which are very clearly handled by the switch statement and a switch makes for a lot less accessing of the controlling variable as the test of that variable only needs to be done once..

Comment: sir i want to ask user parent and then ask child for 1 and then ask child for 2 parent ...Your above program after asking parent terminate nothing show..Not show how much child create

Comment: You could always have each process display some info about itself.  Your question did not say what each process was to accomplish, only how to create the processes.  Suggest you have each process display the results of calls to `getpid()` and `getppid()`

Comment: BTW:  I'm only showing you how to do it, it is up to you to add any details